# Turn 1d array into 2d array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, functional-programming

If I have a one-dimensional array:

`oneDimArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

and I already have a 3X3 two-dimensional array with the right amount of slots to fit the numbers

`twoDimArray = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]`

...how do I fit the oneDimArray numbers into the twoDimArray, like:

`[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`

?

I know I can do this with a couple of nested for-loops, but is there a simpler, functional way to do this?

Comment: (not familiar with Swift) you should be able to do a `reduce` operation or even a recursive algorithm. Not sure what the best tool Swift has for these. If you know the exact number of slots and they follow a pattern, you can derive locations mathematically and do it in a straight loop: `threeDimArray[i / 3][i % 3] = oneDimArray[i]` (where `/` performs integer division).

Comment: Why do you call a 2-dimensional array `threeDimArray`?

Comment: good point @MartinR - updated

Answer (score 9):

Here is one way to do it.  Make an iterator out of your one dimensional array, and then use `map` and `compactMap` along with `.next()` to replace the values of the `twoDimArray` to create the newArray:

```
let oneDimArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let twoDimArray = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]

var iter = oneDimArray.makeIterator()
let newArray = twoDimArray.map { $0.compactMap { _ in iter.next() } }
print(newArray)
```

**Output**

> ```
> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
> ```

---

A nice feature of this technique is that you can easily fill in any pattern of array, and not just create a fixed 3x3 one for instance:

```
let oneDimArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let patternArray = [[0], [0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]

var iter = oneDimArray.makeIterator()
let newArray = patternArray.map { $0.compactMap { _ in iter.next() } }
print(newArray)
```

**Output**

> ```
> [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
> ```

---

**A generic function**

We can turn this into a generic function that can replace the values of a 2D array with those of a 1D array.  Note that the types of the values in the arrays can be different if you like:

```
func overlay<T, U>(_ array: [[T]], values: [U]) -> [[U]] {
    var iter = values.makeIterator()
    return array.map { $0.compactMap { _ in iter.next() }}
}

// Create an 2D array of strings from this pattern   
let patternArray = [[0], [0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]

print(overlay(patternArray, values: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]))
```

**Output**

> ```
> [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i", "j"]]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You can loop over index and value using `enumerated` and then calculate the correct postion using % and /

```
for (index, num) in oneDimArray.enumerated() {
    twoDimArray[index / 3][index % 3] = num
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var index = 0
twoDimArray.indices.forEach { (outerInd) in
    twoDimArray[outerInd].indices.forEach { (innerInd) in
        twoDimArray[outerInd][innerInd] = oneDimArray[index]
        index += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
for i in twoDimArray.indices {
    for j in twoDimArray[i].indices {
        twoDimArray[i][j] = oneDimArray.removeFirst();
    }
}
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.